# Bootstrap Carousal is not working in my code

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, gallery

I'm learning bootstrap these days. I am developing  a main page. But the carousal is not working. Please check the code and tell me which thing i'm missing in my code. I am just copy pasting the code of carousal from w3school. I don't know where i am missing. It'll be great if somebody can help me in this.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>

   <!-- Image and text -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="Solupo_h.png" width="500" height="180" class="d-inline-block align-top" id="header" alt="top header" loading="lazy" >
    </a>
</nav>

<div id="ct">
  <div class="corner "id="left_top"></div>
  <div class="corner" id="left_bottom"></div>
  <div class="corner" id="right_top"></div>
  <div class="corner" id="right_bottom"></div>
  <span>Winston Churchill</span>
  <blockquote>
    <p><i>&ldquo;Success consists of going from failure to failure without loss of enthusiasm.&rdquo; </i></p>
  </blockquote>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- The slideshow -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="654-500x3002.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="654-500x3002.jpg" alt="Chicago">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="654-500x3002.jpg" alt="New York">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>



    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve] using relevant libraries and CSS in the panels - I suggest you use the CDN for both jQuery AND the bootstrap stuff

Comment: can you try placing the jquery and bootstrap scripts inside <head>

Comment: Thank you guys. I'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have downloaded the bootstrap stylesheet or javascript assets. The code is fine since you mentioned that you copy pasted the code directly from w3schools.

You need the following files downloaded and added to your folder:

css/bootstrap.min.css
js/bootstrap.min.js

OR

You can just paste the following in your `<head>` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And you can add the following at the end of your `<body>` tag:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Hope that helps!